# Can pilots confirm or refute that the earth is rotating or not?

Tags: flight-planning

Some people claim that the plane should fly slower in one direction and faster in the other direction, if the earth is rotating.

Comment: Faster or slower relative to what? The ground? Compared to the rotation rate of the (possibly roundish) Earth?

Comment: Question text asks a very different question than the title.

Comment: @StephenS The question text contains no question at all; the only question posed is in the title. Which is clearly answerable (see below). The sentence in the body of the post is vaguely related to the title with the question in it, but the question itself is only asked in one place.

Comment: You are Zeno of Elea and I claim my £5

Comment: I would think if you justbflew due north for x period of ti.e, turned 180 and flew due aouth

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I am a pilot, and I confirm that the Earth is, in fact, rotating. I know this because the sun does not remain in one stationary spot in the sky, but rather appears to move, since the planet upon which we stand is, in fact, rotating.

So yes, pilots can (and do) confirm that the Earth is rotating. That is the question that was asked, and most definitively, the answer is, yes.

Comment: It should be pointed out that you being a pilot has no bearing on your ability to confirm that the Earth is rotating. I can confirm the same thing and I am not a pilot. Also, Maupertuis confirmed the equatorial bulge (the Earth being "pulled apart" and "flattened" by its rotation) in the 1730s, several experimental physicists confirmed the Coriolis effect (objects not falling straight down) in the late 1700s and the most famous experiment, Foucault confirmed it with the pendulum experiment in 1851. None of these people were pilots.

Comment: @JörgWMittag -- re "it should be pointed out  that you being a pilot"-- why should this be pointed out?  The question asked "can pilots confirm...", and the reply said essentially "I am a pilot and I can confirm".  Sounds good to me!